# How to install frameworks in Visual Studio for Mac after the initial installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac, .net-mac

I have installed `Visual Studio for Mac` today but did not toggle `.net` thinking I would install it later as my internet connection was very slow. But now I can't find the place where to install `.net` from. For this thing `Windows` installs a program called `Visual Studio Installer`, but I can't find it on my `Mac`

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool installed with the `Visual Studio for Mac` itself, neither a seperate app on your machine like the `Visual Studio Installer` on `Windows`. To achieve this, you need to redownload the [`Visual Studio for Mac Installer`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) and you will have the option to install the framework you want.

##### Steps:

[image: Visual Studio for Mac Installer in Downloads folder]
[image: Visual Studio for Mac Installer first screen]
[image: Visual Studio for Mac Installer opening]
[image: Visual Studio for Mac Installer showing all the install options]